# Какое регулярное выражение для предпоследнего совпадения?

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Есть такая разметка:

```
<div class="brd">
<ul class="brd-navigation">
    <li><a>Текст</a></li>
    <li><a>Текст</a></li>
    <li><a>Текст</a></li>
    <li><a>Текст_</a></li>
    <li><a>Текст</a></li> 
</ul>
</div>
```

Как вытащить LI в котором "Текст_"?

Comment: Вы мыслите этот вопрос в терминах регэкспов, в то время как есть бы вы мыслили его в терминах DOM-дерева - решить было бы гораздо проще.

Comment: Вы за XPATH? Подскажите?

Answer (score 1):

Самый простой способ - привязываемся к тегу ul. То есть, матчим последние два li и /ul. Где то так

```
<li><a>([^<]+)<\/a><\/li>\s*<li><a>[^<]+<\/a><\/li>\s*<\/ul>
```

Но лучше использовать полноценные парсеры.